# Assigning an instance of a struct to a new const struct instance

Tags: c, struct, c99

I have a public function that does a read operation on a buffer and performs a digest. It has a `const uint8_t *` parameter.

```
void do_digest(const uint8_t *buf, size_t size);
```

Internally, I wrap all pointer-size pairs in a simple buffer struct:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t *buf;
    size_t size;
} myBuffer;
```

However, being a pedantic developer, I'd like to get rid of a warning that states that the constness of the parameter is being stripped when assigned to the `myBuffer` struct.

```
myBuffer foo = { buf, size };  // Warning: discards 'const' qualifier
```

So, the easiest and most explicit solution would be to create a new struct type that works with const buffers:

```
typedef struct {
    const uint8_t *buf;
    size_t size;
} myConstBuffer;

myConstBuffer cfoo = { buf, size }; // No warnings, woohoo!
```

But, there is one issue; internally I pass around pointers to these buffer structs. Now, if I have a mutable `myBuffer` instance and I want to pass it into a function that takes a `myConstBuffer` pointer, I'll get a warning complaining about incompatible types.

```
void some_internal_func(const myConstBuffer *b);

...

myBuffer mutable_buf = { ... };    
some_internal_func(&mutable_buf); // Warning: incompatible types.
```

It seems as if I'm trading one warning for another. Is there a better solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need both constBuffer and buffer? Just make const pointer a member of your buffer.

Comment: The "warning" is actually ill-formed code (some compilers say "warning" and insert imaginary casts), so it's not just being pedantic to want to fix this

Comment: There's not really a nice solution to this problem. One tool you have would be to make a function that accepts a  `myBuffer` and returns a `myConstBuffer`; then you at least avoid casts

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: This is often encountered with functions from the standard library and I don't know of a better solution that to cast the argument such that it includes a `const` qualifier (that is, if you do not choose to ignore the warnings :) )

When a function defines in it's prototype that one of its parameters has the type  `<type> const *` this is not that much a request for you to provide a parameter of type `const` as it is an indication that the function will not attempt to modify content at that address. What the functions does request from you by specifying `const` is that the contents at that address will not be modified by you (possibly from a different thread) during that function call.

Typically you see this in library functions which, typically, are not implemented in C. But if they were, then trying to modify the locations pointed by `<type> *const param` would have lead to a compiler error.

In my view it is **way** more preferable to have a warning related to  `const` than an `incompatible type` since it's much safer to suppress it by casting a variable to `const` when passing it as an argument than to a different type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution, because if you have structs with `const <type> *` and `<type> *` they are not compatible.

However, you can make `buff` a `struct` by itself which contains the size and the data, if you can use C11 or at least C99:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    uint8_t data[];
} Buffer;
```

Note that you cannot create static or auto variables from this, so you have to use `malloc` & friends:

```
size_t buffer_length = 10;
Buffer *buff = malloc(sizeof(*buff) + buffer_length);

if ( buff != NULL ) {
    buff->size = buffer_length;

    ...
```

This `struct` can be passed like `buff` above to `const Buffer *` or `Buffer *`, but you don't need to keep track of the size/length anymore, thus change the interface.

This is called a *flexible array member*. It must be the last member of a `struct`. The `sizeof(Buffer)` is as if the array had 0 entries (which is not allowed in C, but is a gcc-extension legacy for pre-C99 code.

**Update:** Of course this would only make sense if you use this `struct` at all levels. So you only pass this `struct` to all functions which use such an array plus the length/size. Otherwise you would have to copy the data, which is often not wanted (no rule without exception).

Often the design of the internal interfaces takes a good portion of design time when developing software. But as you see now, it's worth the effort.

Comment: But also if the user passes in a pointer and a size then this won't work at all unless you copy the data.  That would avoid the `const` error but probably isn't something that should be done.

Comment: @dave: What do you mean? "also" what? And why would that not work?

Comment: The user passes in the pointer and the size.  You can't place your buffer over there pointer in memory (because you don't control the `size_t` bytes just before it), so your only solution is to copy the entire input data.  That's significantly different from the current data type, and probably not optimal.

Comment: @dave: That's why I wrote "There is no simple solution". Of course you have to change the interfaces, because these are **different** datatypes. But that's the only way to be `const`-correct. C does not reliably track `const`-correctness over multiple indirections. This is one reason you should design your interface thoughtfully. Of course you could also use something like `container_of` from the Linux-Kernel, but that would be very error-prone here and you still had the second argument.

Comment: @dave: This definitively is a custom interface, as the standard library does not use `stdint.h` types. I thought is was obvious you have to change the function arguments, too, because the `struct` now already includes the size, so the second argument would be useless.